# laying out images using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to lay out images coming from a server like this, can anyone help me do this using `recyclerview` or some another view?

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what is so difficult putting this in a listview? You could just start with one image per item of the listview. Pretty standard all.

Answer (score 0):

These steps will be helpful to retrieve the Texts/Images from server:

1) Add library dependency.

2) Write the code to fetch the texts/images from server.

3) Get the images from server and set it on the imageview you have designed.

4) For getting images in recycler view please refer the link below
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score 0):

You may decide to copy & paste this code:

http://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Enjoy!